# CodeIgniter routing with variable in the middle

Tags: codeigniter, routes

I need to write a CI route so that it loads the right controller. I have:

```
$route['en/(:any)/events'] = "en/catalog/events_for_route/$1";
```

It should from `en/VAR1/events` go to `en/catalog/events_for_rout/VAR1`

Why it is not working?

Comment: plese post the whole route.php because you may have someting  before that is making the error

Comment: I agree with @ddjikic - this route is correct by itself - so there must be something affecting it

Comment: you need not only the routes.php but config.php how you want to access do you have mode rewrite how tho you access, do you have a controler and is there an error ....